# How do you determine the nested classes of a class?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In Ruby, how do you determine the nested classes of a class?

Comment: @Tommy: What is that supposed to be....??? Dismembered????.... *turns head left and right trying to read it*

Comment: A really poor attempt at arms and legs apparently!

Comment: @Tommy: You mean \o/? :P

Comment: Bijan, I edited the question to prevent it from being closed senselessly. If you don't agree, you can easily undo this. The next time, I ask you to please put some effort into writing your questions, even if you think the topic one-liner suffices - for instance, this one could have used a piece of example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean nested classes in the following sense:

```
class A
    class B; end
    class C; end
end
```

Where `B` and `C` are 'nested' within `A` then the following should work:

```
class Class
    def nested_classes
        constants.collect { |c| const_get(c) }.
            select { |m| m.instance_of?(Class) }
    end
end

A.nested_classes =>  [A::B, A::C]
```

EDIT: You may need to use constants(false) to prevent constant look-up on modules further up the inheritance chain.